# Converting HTML entities to Unicode Characters in C#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, html-entities, html-encode

I found similar questions and answers for Python and Javascript, but not for C# or any other WinRT compatible language.

The reason I think I need it, is because I'm displaying text I get from websites in a Windows 8 store app. E.g. `&eacute;` should become `é`.

Or is there a better way? I'm not displaying websites or rss feeds, but just a list of websites and their titles.

Comment: Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783817/convert-character-entities-to-their-unicode-equivalents

Comment: Actually it's not. He had a different issue.

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate. That question just had an extra step at the end that you don't need.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I recommend using **[System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode)** and **NOT** `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`.

This is due to the fact that the `System.Web` reference does not exist in Winforms/WPF/Console applications and you can get the exact same result using this class (which is already added as a reference in all those projects).

**Usage:**

```
string s =  System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&eacute;"); // Returns é
```

Comment: "you can get the exact same result using this class" - INCORRECT. Only the HttpUtility implementation will correctly decode &#039; as an apostrophe on WP8.

Comment: In my case, `HttpUtility.HtmlDecoded` do the right thing.

Comment: Good solution, but the disadvantage  with  System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode is you won't find it under .NET Framework 3.5 if you are coding for old Windows 7.

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 13):

Use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` .Read on msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)

```
decodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myEncodedString)
```

Comment: Yep, note that for WinForms or Console application you first have to add reference to the System.Web assembly.

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution but it doesn't decode characters like `&lbrace;` :(

Comment: @l19 Is that a recognized htmlentity? I can't find it in this [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). I did manage to find it in a developmental W3C spec, though. That's probably why it isn't decoded yet.

Answer (score 11):

This might be useful, replaces all (for as far as my requirements go) entities with their unicode equivalent.

```
    public string EntityToUnicode(string html) {
        var replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var regex = new Regex("(&[a-z]{2,5};)");
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(html)) {
            if (!replacements.ContainsKey(match.Value)) { 
                var unicode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(match.Value);
                if (unicode.Length == 1) {
                    replacements.Add(match.Value, string.Concat("&#", Convert.ToInt32(unicode[0]), ";"));
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (var replacement in replacements) {
            html = html.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value);
        }
        return html;
    }
```

Comment: Work for my case, but I edited the regex for "var regex = new Regex("(&[a-z]{2,6};)");"

There is a lot of html character longer than 5 (like $eacute; )

Comment: I'd also suggest changing the regex to `var regex = new Regex("(&[a-zA-Z]{2,7};)");`so that characters such as `&Atilde;` are included.

Answer (score 3):

Different coding/encoding of HTML entities and HTML numbers in Metro App and WP8 App.

## With Windows Runtime Metro App

```
{
    string inStr = "ó";
    string auxStr = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(inStr);
    // auxStr == &#243;
    string outStr = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(auxStr);
    // outStr == ó
    string outStr2 = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&oacute;");
    // outStr2 == ó
}
```

## With Windows Phone 8.0

```
{
    string inStr = "ó";
    string auxStr = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(inStr);
    // auxStr == &#243;
    string outStr = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(auxStr);
    // outStr == &#243;
    string outStr2 = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&oacute;");
    // outStr2 == ó
}
```

To solve this, in WP8, I have implemented the table in [HTML ISO-8859-1 Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) before calling `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()`.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, replaces both common and unicode entities.

```
private static readonly Regex HtmlEntityRegex = new Regex("&(#)?([a-zA-Z0-9]*);");

public static string HtmlDecode(this string html)
{
    if (html.IsNullOrEmpty()) return html;
    return HtmlEntityRegex.Replace(html, x => x.Groups[1].Value == "#"
        ? ((char)int.Parse(x.Groups[2].Value)).ToString()
        : HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(x.Groups[0].Value));
}

[Test]
[TestCase(null, null)]
[TestCase("", "")]
[TestCase("&#39;fark&#39;", "'fark'")]
[TestCase("&quot;fark&quot;", "\"fark\"")]
public void should_remove_html_entities(string html, string expected)
{
    html.HtmlDecode().ShouldEqual(expected);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Improved Zumey method (I can`t comment there). Max char size is in the entity: &exclamation; (11). Upper case in the entities are also possible, ex. À (Source from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references))

```cs
public string EntityToUnicode(string html) {
        var replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var regex = new Regex("(&[a-zA-Z]{2,11};)");
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(html)) {
            if (!replacements.ContainsKey(match.Value)) { 
                var unicode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(match.Value);
                if (unicode.Length == 1) {
                    replacements.Add(match.Value, string.Concat("&#", Convert.ToInt32(unicode[0]), ";"));
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (var replacement in replacements) {
            html = html.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value);
        }
        return html;
    }
```