# "&" and Apostrophe shows up a symbols

Tags: c#, string, xaml, windows-8

I am getting data from a web service end point and place it into a list in a for each loop. The service gets it's data from a Wordpress website.

```
 var list = new ItemList
      (
         (string)data.id.ToString(),
          (string)data.name,

          (string)subcategory

     );
```

I then print this on the XAML page. The code works fine in that it successfully gets the data from the service and prints it on the page of my windows 8 app.

However in `(string)data.name,`, which is the name of the items, if the name contains a "&" it shows up in the app as `$#038;`. Also if a item name contains a "'", apostrophe s, it shows up as `&#8217;.`

EG. D & G, shows up as D $#038; G

The "&" and "'" show up as these weird symbols.

How do I get rid of these and fix it so that they render correctly in the app.

Comment: What happens between (string)data.name and the UI layer? If you debug, does data.name already contain these "weird symbols" (actually just HTML encoded symbols), or does data.name contain only the original & or ' and then the UI ends up showing the symbols?

Comment: @DavidKhaykin The names of items from the web service source shows up fine without these characters. When I use i in the app UI or even when I call the service url in windows powershell to view to results, the name shows up with weird symbols as well.

Comment: @Tester When you say "web service source", are you refering to "web service response"? Or what?

Comment: Well the web service was built to get it's data from a website. This is the source. The names show fine in the website. But when I try to access the names through end points (Eg. www.test.com/items/), whether in my app ui or in power shell, the response show the names with these symbols

Comment: @Tester Are you talking about a *crawler*?

Comment: Is the website wordpress by any chance? In some googling I seem to find that particular character encoding being related to wordpress a lot. Just curious.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin  Yes it is Wordpress

Comment: Ok got it. So you're calling a WebService provided by WordPress, hence you are getting string already encoded from webservice and into your app. It was hard to understand the question the way it was worded.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin Yes that's it

Comment: @Tester for your future questions it makes it a lot easier for people to answer when you include these kinds of details in the question.

Comment: @Tester Please provide a string literal sample of the text you're receiving so we can guide you better... Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert character entities to their unicode equivalents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783817/convert-character-entities-to-their-unicode-equivalents)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Please see the example above

Comment: @Tester I asked you for a string literal! I'm very sure that anyone trying to help you doesn't expect explained examples... Just throw in your question a FULL string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take the risk of giving you a wrong hint, because I guess you're talking about a Windows 8 Store App (XAML), thus you don't have access to every class on .NET, but...

What about decoding HTML entities?

<strike>Check this HttpUtility method: [HtmlUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).</strike>

Check [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is on `System.dll`, thus available for Windows 8 Store Apps.

<strike>You'll need to add a reference to `System.Web` on your Visual Studio project.</strike>

Comment: This doesn't work for these characters. `HtmlDecode` will decode `&amp;` but not `$#038;`.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin I'm going to try myself in a console app... if you're right, I'll delete that answer. Should I guess you downvoted the answer...? Remember I said "I'm going to take the risk..."

Comment: @DavidKhaykin By the way... `$#038;` isn't the text OP is trying to decode. It's what the app shows in the UI, am I wrong?

Comment: You guess correctly. I don't downvote often, but when I do, it's because the answer is wrong.

Comment: Correct, but that implies that something at the receiving end in his app is doing the encoding to result in that character string.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin I believe you guessed a lot of things. Check OP's question: " if the name contains a "&" it shows up in the app as $#038;". **It shows in the app**. This implies **that the Web service client isn't decoding the entities**.

Comment: Other way around -- if the web service result is not encodd and the UI is then something is encoding it before it gets to the UI. I am not guessing but that is how I interpreted it. I asked OP to clarify in a comment.

Comment: Either way, HtmlDecode does not actually decode that string, and OP wants to get rid of the symbols, hence HtmlDecode not being the answer. No need to argue, I removed the downvote.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin I'm trying to "try" the solution... :) I told you if it's not working, I'll remove it.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin `string a = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#038;");` has the expected result. You said " HtmlDecode does not actually decode that string"... Why not? O_o

Comment: @DavidKhaykin I did in a console app. By the way, I really doubt host environment would modify the result...!

Comment: Ok. I surrender my internet card. I had "$#038;" and kept misreading it. Nothing to see here, carry on :)

Comment: @DavidKhaykin Hahaha, no problem! BTW check that OP isn't explaining the problem very well :/ "web service source" what?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I tried `(string)System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(data.title)`, but the synbols stayed, didn't change anything, and `  (string)System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(data.title),` but this throws a build error. "web" namespace not recognized

Comment: @Tester, read Matias' answer again, he says you'll need to add reference to that assembly in your project.

Comment: @Tester What you're calling "symbols" are HTML entities... Try to call things by its name!!! And about "didn't change anything", can you provide the exact string you're trying to decode?

Comment: Also in the question it says data.name, now it's data.title??

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer DO you know of any issues with adding the reference system.web to a windows 8 application in vs 2012? I tried, but can't seem to add it to try your answer. It should be a simple ref add, but I can't find it. I found some articles taht said to change the app Target Framework, but in my properties page, the Target Framework section is greyed out.

Comment: The top of the dialog box for adding a ref has the text "Targeting:.Net for Windows  store apps"

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Found this http://rarcher.azurewebsites.net/Post/PostContent/23, so I cant use this answer

Comment: @Tester Can you try the whole `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` which is an equivalent to `HttpUtility`, but in System.Net? Can you add System.Net?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I tried `(string)WebUtility.HtmlDecode(data.name)`, but I get the error "Best overloaded method match for  `WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)` has some invalid arguments ".

Comment: Does this change the data type or anything?

Comment: @Tester What? No. It decodes a string, so it returns a string. Now you'll need to read the linked MSDN article. Please do you homework!! :)

Comment: Actually i figured it out. I needed to assign the data.name to a string variable first, then user htmldecode on the string variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can [use WebUtility.HtmlDecode Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354.aspx)

Or you can use if you don't want to add additional libraries.

```
public string Decode(string text)
{
    var replacements = new Dictionary<string, char> {
      { "&#8217;", ''' },
      // ...etc
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder( text );

    foreach( var c in replacements.Keys ) {
      sb.Replace( c.ToString(), replacements[c] );
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Apart of your "primitive solution", isn't almost the same answer as one provided by me...? :D

Comment: I hadn't seen your answer when I posted mine.

Comment: I was writing my "primitive solution"

Comment: Ok ok... sometimes happens this! About the "primitive solution", you know I'm right about calling it like that! :P

Comment: @DanielGrankin I tried ` (string)System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(data.title),`, but it didn't fix anything.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer It's not so primitive, you have not noticed mistake there even:) Tupitsa!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the service is returning XML escaped entities.  `&#038;` means a character with a code of (decimal) 38 (which is `&`).  `&#8217;` is similar and means a code of 8217 (which is `’`).

You can decode these using `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(inputString)`, but that requires a reference to System.Web.  If you don't want to or cannot reference that, you can try something like this:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml("<x>" + inputString + "</x>");
var output = xml.InnerText;
```

Given `Testing &#8217;stuff&quot; &#038; things`, it will return `Testing ’stuff" & things`.

I'd go with `HtmlDecode()` if you can, but absolutely try and avoid rolling your own decoder unless you have no other choice.

Comment: I tried this but I get build errors. I an't seem to reference system.web.

Comment: You probably just need to include a reference to System.Web in Visual Studio. Right-click on References, choose Add Reference. Under Assemblies you should be able to find System.Web.

Comment: I just commented on this below. I can't seem to find it. My app is a windows 8 store app. When I go to add a ref, under assemblies, it says at the top, Targeting:.Net for Windows  store apps